# Spring Security Returns 403 After Successfully Authenticating

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am attempting to allow users to authenticate through a login page as well as through an API call.  I had it working at one point, but after messing around with the code, I don't recall if my getting one thing to work caused something else to break.  The login page works fine, but calling an endpoint through the use of a curl is giving me a 403 error.  This occurs at chain.doFilter() in AuthenticationFilter.

Curl statement:

```
curl -XPOST "http:/localhost:8080/api/dothis" -H "accept: application/json" -F 'data=@path/to/cert'
```

MultipleSecurityConfig.java

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class MultipleSecurityConfig {

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    public class LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        String[] permitted = {
                "/login",
                "/error",
                "/images/**"
        };

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(permitted).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/swagger-ui.html", true)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);
        }
    }
}
```

AuthenticationFilter.java

```java
//optional default is POST
con.setRequestMethod("POST");

//add request header
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + URL);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
    wr.write(postData);
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
}
else {
    System.out.println("Error creating HTTPS connection");
    System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode + ", Response Message: " + con.getResponseMessage());
    result = null;
}
if(result.toString().contains("\"successful\": true")) {
    http_response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: I included another chain.doFilter() before setting up the connection in the authentication filter, which somehow allowed the second method to bypass where it was stuck and enter the code for the requested API method, but I have no idea how that could have worked.  Also, this does not solve my issue as it still returns a 403 response after returning from the API method.

Comment: I didn't get why you are trying to initiate an http request in your `AuthenticationFilter` and I think it is not the proper way to authenticate every api request automatically in the filter unless you have a very specific need. It should be the client's responsibility to provide the necessary credentials (password, token, certificate, etc.) in order to authenticate itself. If any details you can provide about your needs maybe we can find another solution.